# Php with undefined data

Tags: php, input, http-post, http-get

I've got php files from server, but there is a problem. Those files uses input forms, also getting data via link requests. Surprise is, there is no `$_POST` or `$_GET` uses at all. I'm using basic configuration of XAMPP, so it results in a lot of define errors.

I had to add `$_POST` to make part of it work **the way it works on a server**, but editing all of php files would be pain.

So the questions is, how can I set php so that it will work with undefined data?

Answer (score 1):

Test to see if user input exists before trying to use it.

```
$foo = "Default value";
if (isset($_GET['foo'])) {
    $foo = $_GET['foo']; 
}
```

Comment: Excellent translation skills, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
extract($_GET, EXTR_SKIP);
```

Placed them in the starting position of your php file.

eh ...

```
error_reporting(0);
```